# How to embed Javascript file in Blazor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor WASM (Client) project, where I have a javascript file interop.js.
I copied this in the wwwroot folder and called this way in the _Host.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Client</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/interop.js"></script>
</head>
```

No matter what ever I do, the browser debugger window shows this warning message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)      Interop.js:1
```

Why would this be happening ?

Somebody please help !!!

Thank you

Comment: Blazor wasm doesn't have `_Host.cshtml` but the devs are planning to support it. See here [Update the ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly template to use _Host.cshtml](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25631)

Comment: In index.html in wwwroot folder you can add your reference to the js file there, thats what i do, then any functions inside it you can call with js interop.